# Not able to connect Google Cloud Datastore with AEM 6.5 : Bundle has resolved dependencies

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, aem

I have a requirement to connect google cloud datastore from AEM. I have added the dependencies in main pom and core pom.

MAIN POM

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>16.4.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>de here
```

Core POM

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I deploy my bundle is in insatlled state and has the following errors

```
com.google.auth -- Cannot be resolved
com.google.auth.oauth2 -- Cannot be resolved
com.google.cloud -- Cannot be resolved
com.google.cloud.datastore -- Cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding those libs to the embed-dependencies in the POM. Also check that your libs are inside the .jar file generated.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <!-- <Embed-Dependency> artifactId1, artifactId2;inline=true </Embed-Dependency> -->
                    <Export-Package>we.retail.core.model*</Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>we.retail.core*</Private-Package> 
                    <Sling-Model-Packages>
                        we.retail.core.model
                    </Sling-Model-Packages>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In the embed you can try something like: google-cloud-datastore

Also take care with the import type that you're using.
[image]

[Link to Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Hope you can find the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need those, exclude them from the `<Import-Packages>`:

```
<Import-Package>
!com.google.auth.*,
*
</Import-Package>
```